# Can a Visual Studio Quick Fix interact with user or host?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, roslyn, analyzer

We are creating an [Analyzer](http://www.filehelpers.net) with quickfixes and would be great if we can interact with the user

For example we want to open a web site, show a form (for example a wizard) or get a Host instance (via DTE)

For example when Visual Studio shows the bobble instead of the quick fix we want to open a form:

[image: Analyzer]

We can do something like that, or the analyzers are run using a sandbox in Visual Studio 2015 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do so via the analyzer/diagnostic approach. (I've waited to respond just in case someone knew it would be possible wanted to reply).

However, I'm fairly sure you can accomplish what you'd like to via a "Light Bulb Suggestion". Light Bulb suggestions are a little more complex than analyzers, but more customizable.

A full walkthrough can be found on MSDN: [Walkthrough: Displaying Light Bulb Suggestions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn903708.aspx).

In particular, you should take a look at [`GetPreviewAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.language.intellisense.isuggestedaction.getpreviewasync.aspx). Their implementation is as follows:

```
public Task<object> GetPreviewAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var textBlock = new TextBlock();
    textBlock.Padding = new Thickness(5);
    textBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run() { Text = m_upper });
    return Task.FromResult<object>(textBlock);
}
```

In this case they're returning a `TextBlock`, but you should be able to return your custom form at this point.

You'll also have to implement the other methods in [`ISuggestedAction`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.language.intellisense.isuggestedaction.aspx) to get everything hooked up.

You can actually look at see that all Roslyn related Light Bulb actions implement `ISuggestAction`. Their implementation is available in the [`SuggestedAction`](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EditorFeatures/Implementation/Suggestions/SuggestedAction.cs,72ee6a717bc09afb,references) class.

Comment: Great point !! that is what we need. I will try to go this way, and deploy both addins in the same vsix